# Call of nonfunction, also text not showing up

Tags: c++, loops, dosbox

Please help I need this done tomorrow and have not been able to receive any help from my school sources.

The first section with username functions, however it takes in first and last name as well as display message but does not display the actual username created and only the empty message. Please if you can fix this I'll be very grateful. My factorial work requires a loop to continue the input of possible numbers to factorize but I have no idea where to put it.

Please if anyone can help me I need this

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void displayName (char Username[20])
{
            cout << "Username created is: " << Username<<endl;
}

void Create_Username (char lastName[10],char firstName[10])
{
        char Username [20];
        strncpy( Username, firstName, 1);
        strcat ( Username, lastName);

        strlwr(Username);
        memset (Username, 0, 20);

        displayName(Username);
}
void Get_Name()
{
    char firstName [10];
    char lastName [10];

    cout << "\nPlease enter first name" ;
    cin >> firstName;

    cout << "\nPlease enter last name";
    cin >> lastName;

    Create_Username(lastName, firstName);
}


void display_Factorial(int Number, int Factorial)
{
    cout << "Number entered is\n"<< Number << endl;
    cout << "Factorial answer is\n" << Factorial << endl;
}
void Calculate_factorial(int Number)
{
        int Factorial;
        int Calculate;

        if (Number<0)
            cout << " That cannot be factorised. \n";

        else
    cout << Number << " The factorial result is:" << Factorial(Number) <<   endl;


            Calculate = Number * Factorial(Number - 1);



      display_Factorial(Number, Factorial);

}
void getNumber()
{
    int Number;

    cout<< "\n Please enter number to be factorised";
    cin>> Number;


  Calculate_factorial(Number);

}

void menuInterface()
{
    int menu_option;
    do
    {
        cout<<"\n 1. Create Username\n";
        cout<<"\n 2. Calculate factorial\n";
        cout<<"\n 3. Exit menu\n";
        cin >> menu_option;

    switch (menu_option)
    {
        case 1:
        Get_Name();
        getch();
        break;

        case 2:
        getNumber();
        getch();
        break;

        case 3:
        cout<< "\n You have chosen to exit the menu\n";
        getch();
        break;
    }
    }
while (menu_option !=3);

}

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    menuInterface();

}
```

Errors:

- 54: Call of nonfunction
- 57: Call of nonfunction

Comment: The is no function called Factorial.

Comment: I made an oopsie, hold on

Comment: May or may not have somehow missed the last bit of it. It's there now, please have another look

Comment: From the header files that you are including, it seems you are using an extremely old version of a C++ compiler. Don't you want to use something a bit more modern?

Comment: If I remember `memset` correctly, you are resetting Username to all NULL values *before* displaying it, move the call to memset to after the call to `displayName(Username);` The specific errors about Call of nonfunction is mentioned in previous comments.

Comment: Not using this by choice.

Comment: "Not using this by choice." -- Please tell me this is a high school (or lower) setting. Using old equipment in non-post secondary education I can understand, but in a college or university setting is just wrong. There are free alternatives for everything.

Comment: It is college, sadly. Gonna try doing what you said.

Comment: So, in the memset, if I don't use all 10 characters for my first name, it puts these squiggles between the first and last name. Any ideas there?

Answer (score 1):

On the line that says:

`cout << Number << " The factorial result is:" << Factorial(Number) << endl;`

what/where is this `Factorial()` function at??

Seems like you are missing `Factorial()` function since you called it twice in `calculate_factorial()`. Also, the compiler is also telling you that you are calling something that is not yet a function 3 lines apart, which is pointing right at that that line I mentioned

Comment: Could I ask where you would put Factorial()?

Comment: Anywhere above calculate_factorial since you aren't prototyping.  It must come before when it is called so program knows it exists.

Comment: Be careful because you are also initializing a variable called `Factorial` in your `Calculate_factorial()` function.  You might wanna change the name of that variable.

Comment: Any number that is 13 or above doesn't come out correctly, any idea why that might be?

Oh, and I did change it to long long.